# What is the best way to transpose a data.frame in R and to set one of the columns to be the header for the new transposed table?

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

What is the best way to transpose a data.frame in R and to set one of the columns to be the header for the new transposed table? I have coded up a way to do this below. As I am still new to R. I would like suggestions to improve my code as well as alternatives that would be more R-like. My solution is also unfortunately a bit hard coded (i.e. the new column headings are in a certain location).

```
# Assume a data.frame called fooData
# Assume the column is the first column before transposing

# Transpose table
fooData.T <- t(fooData)

# Set the column headings
colnames(fooData.T) <- test[1,]

# Get rid of the column heading row
fooData.T <- fooData.T[2:nrow(fooData.T), ]

#fooData.T now contains a transposed table with the first column as headings
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R-Transposing a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778908/r-transposing-a-data-frame)

Comment: With `as.data.frame(t(df))`, the row names and column names are transposed and the data remains numeric, where `df` is a dataframe.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well you could do it in 2 steps by using

```
# Transpose table YOU WANT
fooData.T <- t(fooData[,2:ncol(fooData)])

# Set the column headings from the first column in the original table
colnames(fooData.T) <- fooData[,1]
```

The result being a matrix which you're probably aware of, that's due to class issues when transposing. I don't think there will be a single line way to do this given the lack of naming abilities in the transpose step.

Comment: Good point, this should make it faster as far as I can tell, as it is having to transpose less data. Plus looks neater. The matrix issue is one of the issues I ran into also and had to use a class(fooData.T) <- "numeric", which won't work for any other data types.

Comment: I am making this the answer as there aren't any other alternatives, which is strange for programming as there is usually a multitude of ways to solve something.

Comment: There is a problem with the second instruction, it should be `colnames(fooData.T) <- t(fooData[,1])`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it even in one line:

```
fooData.T <- setNames(data.frame(t(fooData[,-1])), fooData[,1])
```

There are already great answers. However, this answer might be useful for those who prefer brevity in code.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents using `dplyr` for a `data.frame` that has grouping columns and an `id` column.

```
id_transpose <- function(df, id){
  df %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    setNames(., df %>% pull({{id}}))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tiyderse/dplyr` approach taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306280/how-to-transpose-a-dataframe-in-tidyverse).

```
mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%  
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from=rowname, values_from=value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `transpose` from `data.table`, suppose the column you want to use as header after transpose is the variable `group`.

```
fooData.transpose = fooData %>% transpose (make.name = "group")
```

In addition, if you want to assign a name for the transposed column name, use argument `keep.names`.

```
fooData.transpose = fooData %>% transpose (make.name = "group", keep.names = "column_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's now a dedicated function to transpose data frames, `rotate_df` from the `sjmisc` package. If the desired names are in the first column of the original df, you can achieve this in one line thanks to the `cn` argument.

Here's an example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Mary", "John", "Louise"), class = c("A", "A", "B"), score = c(40, 75, 80))

df
#    name class score
#1   Mary     A    40
#2   John     A    75
#3 Louise     B    80
```

Executing the function with `cn = T`:

```
rotate_df(df, cn = T)

#      Mary John Louise
#class    A    A      B
#score   40   75     80
```

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem to this -- I had a variable of factors in a long format and I wanted each factor to be a new column heading; using "unstack" from the stats library did it in one step.  If the column you want as a header isn't a factor, "cast" from the reshape library might work.