# Transpose a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to transpose a large data frame and so I used:

```
df.aree <- t(df.aree)
df.aree <- as.data.frame(df.aree)
```

This is what I obtain:

```
df.aree[c(1:5),c(1:5)]
                         10428        10760        12148        11865
    name                M231T3       M961T5       M960T6      M231T19
    GS04.A        5.847557e+03 0.000000e+00 3.165891e+04 2.119232e+04
    GS16.A        5.248690e+04 4.047780e+03 3.763850e+04 1.187454e+04
    GS20.A        5.370910e+03 9.518396e+03 3.552036e+04 1.497956e+04
    GS40.A        3.640794e+03 1.084391e+04 4.651735e+04 4.120606e+04
```

My problem is the new column names(10428, 10760, 12148, 11865) that I need to eliminate because I need to use the first row as column names.

I tried with `col.names()` function but I haven't obtain what I need.

Do you have any suggestion?

EDIT

Thanks for your suggestion!!! Using it I obtain:

```
df.aree[c(1:5),c(1:5)]
                        M231T3       M961T5       M960T6      M231T19
    GS04.A        5.847557e+03 0.000000e+00 3.165891e+04 2.119232e+04
    GS16.A        5.248690e+04 4.047780e+03 3.763850e+04 1.187454e+04
    GS20.A        5.370910e+03 9.518396e+03 3.552036e+04 1.497956e+04
    GS40.A        3.640794e+03 1.084391e+04 4.651735e+04 4.120606e+04
    GS44.A        1.225938e+04 2.681887e+03 1.154924e+04 4.202394e+04
```

Now I need to transform the row names(GS..) in a factor column....

Comment: Have you tried `colnames(df.aree)<-df.aree[1,];df.aree<-df.aree[2:nrow(df.aree),]`?

Comment: Data frames aren't naturally meant to be transposable.  If yours is, then perhaps it should be in matrix form instead.

Comment: Agree; `t`ing data frame is also quite inefficient. If you can, use matrix.

Comment: Transposing a data.frame that contains a string column in it turns ALL values into strings! NOT good. See my answer below for a work-around.

Answer (score 136):

You'd better not transpose the data.frame while the name column is in it - all numeric values will then be turned into strings!

Here's a solution that keeps numbers as numbers:

```
# first remember the names
n <- df.aree$name

# transpose all but the first column (name)
df.aree <- as.data.frame(t(df.aree[,-1]))
colnames(df.aree) <- n
df.aree$myfactor <- factor(row.names(df.aree))

str(df.aree) # Check the column types
```

Comment: If you want to use transpose with data.frame, df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.numeric) can be used to change characters back to numeric.

Answer (score 85):

You can use the `transpose` function from the `data.table` library. Simple and fast solution that keeps `numeric` values as `numeric`.

```
library(data.table)

# get data
data("mtcars")

# transpose
t_mtcars <- transpose(mtcars)

# get row and colnames in order
colnames(t_mtcars) <- rownames(mtcars)
rownames(t_mtcars) <- colnames(mtcars)
```

Comment: also, `setnames(t_mtcars, rownames(mtcars))` would be the `data.table`-way of setting names on a data.table (and if using a `data.table` object you wouldn't set the `rownames`)

Comment: Also, within `data.table::transpose` you can use the arguments `make.names` to select the column (usually a character vector) whose names will become the column names for the transposed data.frame. You can also use the argument `keep.names` to choose a column name for the new column (a character vector) which will store the previous column names from the pre-transposed data.frame).

Answer (score 50):

```
df.aree <- as.data.frame(t(df.aree))
colnames(df.aree) <- df.aree[1, ]
df.aree <- df.aree[-1, ]
df.aree$myfactor <- factor(row.names(df.aree))
```

Comment: @Riccardo If so, accept his answer by clicking a gray tick next to it.

Comment: one problem with this - column names take the numeric representation of the factor level.

Answer (score 5):

With **tidyr**, one can transpose a dataframe with "pivot_longer" and then "pivot_wider".

To transpose the widely used mtcars dataset, you should first transform rownames to a column (the function **rownames_to_column** creates a new column, named "rowname").

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
rownames_to_column() %>% 
pivot_longer(!rowname, names_to = "col1", values_to = "col2") %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = "rowname", values_from = "col2")
```

Answer (score 4):

Take advantage of `as.matrix`:

```
# keep the first column 
names <-  df.aree[,1]

# Transpose everything other than the first column
df.aree.T <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(t(df.aree[,-1])))

# Assign first column as the column names of the transposed dataframe
colnames(df.aree.T) <- names
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give another name for transpose matrix

```
df.aree1 <- t(df.aree)
df.aree1 <- as.data.frame(df.aree1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).