# Pivot a dataframe in r and add a column with custom value

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I want to pivot a data frame
My input data is as

*1st Input*

```
MSFT    AAPL    GOOG
10      20      40
```

*1st output*

```
Id  Symbol  Value
T1  MSFT    10
T1  AAPL    20
T1  GOOG    40
```

--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
*2nd Input*

```
AAPL    GOOG
30      60
```

*2nd output*

```
Id  Symbol  Value
T2  AAPL    30
T2  GOOG    60
```

---------------------------------------------------------------------
`Input1` and `Input2` are generated in a for loop. Can a single line of `R` code can solve for both of these so that the final output is as follows.

```
Id  Symbol  Value
T1  MSFT    10
T1  AAPL    20
T1  GOOG    40
T2  AAPL    30
T2  GOOG    60
```

**Performance is must**. I have seen on other questions on Stackoverflow that `rbind` or `list` provide less performance than preallocated space.

Comment: Have a look at `gather()` from the package `tidyr`. There is also a base R function `reshape` that can do what you want, but `tidyr` is much more user-friendly.

Comment: the following link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778908/r-transposing-a-data-frame

Comment: Are your inputs lists, named vectors, data frames, what? Define them. As it stands, the easiest way to make the 1st and second outputs is to rotate my head 90 degrees..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your orginal data are:

```
> df1
  MSFT AAPL GOOG
1   10   20   40
```

Without dplyr and plyr but reshape package (for rename):

```
toggle <- function(df, id){
    rename(transform(t(df), id=id, Symbol=rownames(t(df)), c("X_data"="Value"))

}

rbindlist(list(toggle(df1,'T1'), toggle(df2,'T2')))
```

Comment: indeed that might be the case! Corrected, still the input data are not mentionned in a very clear format in the question ;)

Comment: Don't assume these things. Ask the poster for clarification. And vote down as unclear. Its what comments and votes are for!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it with dplyr and tidyr (as commented by konvas):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- gather(df1, Symbol, Value, MSFT:GOOG) %>% mutate(Id = "T1")
df2 <- gather(df2, Symbol, Value, AAPL:GOOG) %>% mutate(Id = "T2")
dfs <- rbind_list(df1, df2)
```

The same could be written in "a single line of R code" as asked for in the question:

```
rbind_list(gather(df1, Symbol, Value, MSFT:GOOG) %>% mutate(Id = "T1"),
           gather(df2, Symbol, Value, AAPL:GOOG) %>% mutate(Id = "T2"))
```

Or using `reshape2` and base R's `rbind`:

```
library(reshape2)
rbind(transform(melt(df1), Id = "T1"), transform(melt(df2), Id = "T2"))
```

Comment: rbindlist(list(...)) is faster.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, then congrats for implementing it in your answer :)

Comment: Regarding performance, a quote from `rbind_list`: "This is an efficient version of the common pattern of do.call(rbind, dfs) for row-binding many data frames together. It works in the same way as rbind.fill but is implemented in C++ so avoids many copies and is much much faster."

Answer (score 4):

Syntax-wise this is succinct:

```
reshape2::melt(list(T1=Input1, T2=Input2))
#   variable value L1
# 1     MSFT    10 T1
# 2     AAPL    20 T1
# 3     GOOG    40 T1
# 4     AAPL    30 T2
# 5     GOOG    60 T2
```

However it internally uses `rbind.fill` which [doesn't scale well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18004698/559784) (albeit an old benchmark). There's another [interesting link/post](http://crowding.github.io/plyr/rbind-fill.html) I came across while searching for `rind.fill` slowness.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use `unnest/gather/filter` combo from `tidyr/dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
unnest(setNames(list(Input1, Input2), paste0("T",1:2)),'Id') %>%
                                   gather(Symbol, Value, -Id) %>% 
                                   filter(!is.na(Value))
#  Id Symbol Value
#1 T1   MSFT    10
#2 T1   AAPL    20
#3 T2   AAPL    30
#4 T1   GOOG    40
#5 T2   GOOG    60
```

#### data

```
 Input1 <- structure(list(MSFT = 10L, AAPL = 20L, GOOG = 40L), .Names =
  c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

 Input2 <- structure(list(AAPL = 30L, GOOG = 60L), .Names = c("AAPL", "GOOG"
 ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```