# Formatting Numbers in Flextable for Specific Columns

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable

I'm using R version 3.6.1 in RStudio. I have flextable version 0.5.5 and officer version 0.3.5.

I'm having difficulty with formatting my numbers in flextables within RMarkdown. By default, all numbers show up with 3 decimal places. For some of my numbers, this is fine (and actually preferred), but for others, I want to remove the decimals.

Using the advice found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090341/format-numbers-in-flextable) I was able to adjust my table so that all numbers are rounded to the nearest whole number. My code is below (example table used for reproduciblility; otherwise formatting is the same as my current code).

```
ft_test <- head(iris) %>% flextable() %>% 
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>% 
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>% 
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>% 
    set_formatter_type(fmt_double = "%.0f")
ft_test
```

However, I only want certain columns to be whole numbers, and other columns to still have decimals. I've tried using the `j` argument to call certain columns:

```
ft_test <- head(iris) %>% flextable() %>% 
    hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>% 
    align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>% 
    align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>% 
    set_formatter_type(fmt_double = "%.0f", j = 2)
ft_test
```

... but then I get an error telling me `j = 2` is an unused argument.

Any suggestions for how to adjust the numbers of only **some** columns? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use argument `j` as it is not an argument of `set_formatter_type`. The function is setting formatters for one or several data type. In your case, it's better to use `colformat_num`.

```
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

ft_test <- head(iris) %>% flextable() %>% 
  hline(part = 'header', border = fp_border(color = "black", width = 3)) %>% 
  align(align ='center', part = 'all') %>% 
  align(j = 1, align ='left', part = 'all') %>% 
  colformat_num(j = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",
                             "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"), digits = 1)
ft_test
```

[image]

You can learn more about formatting content here: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/display.html

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems like this solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I wonder, is there any other solution that would allow formatting a set of columns according to the same pattern (e.g., one digit after the comma).

Comment: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/display.html

Comment: Downvoted because when I change the value of `digits` to 0 or 2, the table still is produced with 1 decimal place.

Comment: I just discovered that `colformat_double` works in place of `colformat_num`. i would upvote the answer but SO isn't allowing me to change the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that you can just do it by running before the creation of the `flexible`:

```
set_flextable_defaults(digits = 1)
```

It worked for me.