# How to transpose certain set of columns

Tags: r

I have a data set with over 300 columns and rows that looks like this:

```
old= data.frame(
    id=1:3,
    DATE=c('20/12/1965','11/101970','03/12/1985'),
    TRT=c(1,2,1),
    AT1=c(40,89,50),
    AT2=c(18,43,13),
    AT3=c(23,16,10),
    BECT1=c(80,50,60),
    BECT2=c(78,40,48),
    BECT3=c(60,97,56),
    C0T1=c(43,45,78),
    C0T2=c(42,NA,48))
```

I want to transpose my data to look like this:

```
new=data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
           TRT=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1),
           DATE=c('20/12/1965','20/12/1965','20/12/1965','11/10/1970','11/10/1970','11/10/1970','03/12/1985','03/12/1985','03/12/1985'),        
           variable1=c('ATI','AT2','AT3','ATI','AT2','AT3','ATI','AT2','AT3'), 
           value1=c(20,23,18,89,43,16,50,13,10),
           variable2=c('BECT1','BECT2','BECT3','BECT1','BECT2','BECT3','BECT1','BECT2','BECT3'), 
           value2=c(80,78,60,50,40,97,60,48,56),
           Variable3= c('C0T1','C0T2','C0T3','C0T1','C0T2','C0T3','C0T1','C0T2','C0T3'), 
           value3=c(43,42,85,45,63,NA,78,48,48))
```

thanks

Comment: Your `new` dataframe is giving an error.

Comment: OK, so what problem did you run into when doing it? Did you read existing answers on transposing and reshaping data?... and yes, your 2nd line of code has an error. If you just want to transpose use `t()`. If you want to reshape read any of the dozens of existing questions and answers on that topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R-Transposing a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778908/r-transposing-a-data-frame)

Comment: I did read it, the problem I had was that I was unable to get the required result using reshape and t(). I wanted to transpose based on column clusters rather than all the columns at the same time

Comment: You have at least one error in your input and one in your output. A date is missing a slash in the input, and I do not see where value1 got 20 for AT1 from, given that AT1 in the input shows 40, 89 and 50 as its values. Could you submit the expected response in the form of actual data, as opposed to code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gather` from the `tidyr` package, and arrange from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
old_df= data.frame(
    id=1:3,
    DATE=c('20/12/1965','11/10/1970','03/12/1985'),
    TRT=c(1,2,1),
    AT1=c(40,89,50),
    AT2=c(18,43,13),
    AT3=c(23,16,10),
    BECT1=c(80,50,60),
    BECT2=c(78,40,48),
    BECT3=c(60,97,56),
    C0T1=c(43,45,78),
    C0T2=c(42,NA,48))

new_df <- old_df %>%
    gather(AT1, AT2, AT3, key = "variable1", value = "value1") %>%
    gather(BECT1, BECT2, BECT3, key = "variable2", value = "value2") %>%
    gather(C0T1, C0T2, key = "variable3", value = "value3") %>%
    arrange(id, DATE, TRT, variable1, variable2, variable3)

   id       DATE TRT variable1 value1 variable2 value2 variable3 value3
1   1 20/12/1965   1       AT1     40     BECT1     80      C0T1     43
2   1 20/12/1965   1       AT1     40     BECT1     80      C0T2     42
3   1 20/12/1965   1       AT1     40     BECT2     78      C0T1     43
4   1 20/12/1965   1       AT1     40     BECT2     78      C0T2     42
5   1 20/12/1965   1       AT1     40     BECT3     60      C0T1     43
6   1 20/12/1965   1       AT1     40     BECT3     60      C0T2     42
7   1 20/12/1965   1       AT2     18     BECT1     80      C0T1     43
8   1 20/12/1965   1       AT2     18     BECT1     80      C0T2     42
9   1 20/12/1965   1       AT2     18     BECT2     78      C0T1     43
10  1 20/12/1965   1       AT2     18     BECT2     78      C0T2     42
11  1 20/12/1965   1       AT2     18     BECT3     60      C0T1     43
12  1 20/12/1965   1       AT2     18     BECT3     60      C0T2     42
13  1 20/12/1965   1       AT3     23     BECT1     80      C0T1     43
14  1 20/12/1965   1       AT3     23     BECT1     80      C0T2     42
15  1 20/12/1965   1       AT3     23     BECT2     78      C0T1     43
16  1 20/12/1965   1       AT3     23     BECT2     78      C0T2     42
17  1 20/12/1965   1       AT3     23     BECT3     60      C0T1     43
18  1 20/12/1965   1       AT3     23     BECT3     60      C0T2     42
19  2 11/10/1970   2       AT1     89     BECT1     50      C0T1     45
20  2 11/10/1970   2       AT1     89     BECT1     50      C0T2     NA
21  2 11/10/1970   2       AT1     89     BECT2     40      C0T1     45
22  2 11/10/1970   2       AT1     89     BECT2     40      C0T2     NA
23  2 11/10/1970   2       AT1     89     BECT3     97      C0T1     45
24  2 11/10/1970   2       AT1     89     BECT3     97      C0T2     NA
25  2 11/10/1970   2       AT2     43     BECT1     50      C0T1     45
26  2 11/10/1970   2       AT2     43     BECT1     50      C0T2     NA
27  2 11/10/1970   2       AT2     43     BECT2     40      C0T1     45
28  2 11/10/1970   2       AT2     43     BECT2     40      C0T2     NA
29  2 11/10/1970   2       AT2     43     BECT3     97      C0T1     45
30  2 11/10/1970   2       AT2     43     BECT3     97      C0T2     NA
31  2 11/10/1970   2       AT3     16     BECT1     50      C0T1     45
32  2 11/10/1970   2       AT3     16     BECT1     50      C0T2     NA
33  2 11/10/1970   2       AT3     16     BECT2     40      C0T1     45
34  2 11/10/1970   2       AT3     16     BECT2     40      C0T2     NA
35  2 11/10/1970   2       AT3     16     BECT3     97      C0T1     45
36  2 11/10/1970   2       AT3     16     BECT3     97      C0T2     NA
37  3 03/12/1985   1       AT1     50     BECT1     60      C0T1     78
38  3 03/12/1985   1       AT1     50     BECT1     60      C0T2     48
39  3 03/12/1985   1       AT1     50     BECT2     48      C0T1     78
40  3 03/12/1985   1       AT1     50     BECT2     48      C0T2     48
41  3 03/12/1985   1       AT1     50     BECT3     56      C0T1     78
42  3 03/12/1985   1       AT1     50     BECT3     56      C0T2     48
43  3 03/12/1985   1       AT2     13     BECT1     60      C0T1     78
44  3 03/12/1985   1       AT2     13     BECT1     60      C0T2     48
45  3 03/12/1985   1       AT2     13     BECT2     48      C0T1     78
46  3 03/12/1985   1       AT2     13     BECT2     48      C0T2     48
47  3 03/12/1985   1       AT2     13     BECT3     56      C0T1     78
48  3 03/12/1985   1       AT2     13     BECT3     56      C0T2     48
49  3 03/12/1985   1       AT3     10     BECT1     60      C0T1     78
50  3 03/12/1985   1       AT3     10     BECT1     60      C0T2     48
51  3 03/12/1985   1       AT3     10     BECT2     48      C0T1     78
52  3 03/12/1985   1       AT3     10     BECT2     48      C0T2     48
53  3 03/12/1985   1       AT3     10     BECT3     56      C0T1     78
54  3 03/12/1985   1       AT3     10     BECT3     56      C0T2     48
```

You can read more about gathering in section 12.3.1 of [Hadley Wickham's r4ds book](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
transposeData <- function(df) {
    rowList <- list()
    # store each column as a vector in a list
    for (i in seq_along(df)) {
        rowList[[i]] <- t(df[, i])
    }
    # combine each component (vector) of the list by row
    newDf <- do.call(what = rbind, args = rowList)
    newDf <- as.data.frame(newDf)
    # gives the names of the columns as rownames in the new data
    rownames(newDf) <- names(df)
    # name the column of the new data as the observation index
    names(newDf) <- paste("obs", 1:dim(df)[1])
    newDf  
}
```

The **output** is a data frame with the observations as columns.

```
>transposeData(old)
        obs 1 obs 2 obs 3
id        1     2     3
DATE      3     2     1
TRT       1     2     1
AT1      40    89    50
AT2      18    43    13
AT3      23    16    10
BECT1    80    50    60
BECT2    78    40    48
BECT3    60    97    56
C0T1     43    45    78
C0T2     42    NA    48
```

The problem of the **DATE** column is that was coerce as factor when you create the data frame. So then, inside the for of `transposeData()` function, when the column is extracted as a vector, you obtain the factor level index, not the date. You can fix this with a conditional `if`.

Comment: Thanks but the function melted the columns into three columns instead of nine.

Comment: Please, explain more information about your question. Specifically about your example data.