# very simple pivot of dataframe in r

Tags: r

Can someone please tell me how to get from dataframe `df` to the dataframe desired in the below reproducible code example, please? It is basically just a simple pivot. Thanks!

```
id <- c(1, 2)
x <- c('a', 'b')
y <- c('c', 'd')

df <- data.frame(id, x, y)

head(df)

c1 <- c('id', 'x', 'y')
c2 <- c('1', 'a', 'c')
c3 <- c('2', 'b', 'd')

desired <- data.frame(c1, c2, c3)

head(desired)
```

This seems to work (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778908/transpose-a-data-frame)):

```
test <- transpose(df)
colnames(test) <- rownames(df)
rownames(test) <- colnames(df)
```

but is it the best approach?

Comment: `setNames(data.frame(names(df), t(df)), paste0("c", 1:3))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one liner would be

```
setNames(data.frame(names(df), t(df)), paste0("c", 1:3))
```

A more general solution, without hardcoding the vector `1:3` is

```
setNames(data.frame(names(df), t(df)), paste0("c", seq_along(names(df))))
```