# Changing Table structure in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I want to change the shape of the following table

[image: input table]

to

[image: expected result]

using pandas dataframe. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transpose a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778908/transpose-a-data-frame)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this `transpose` function:

```
numpy.transpose(df)
```

Comment: `df.T` is probably more straightforward access to the transposition.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following for your case supposing that the data frame that you are using is called `df` and you still want to preserve the column labels (titles):

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'Country/Region': [1, 2], 'Afghanistan': [3, 4]} # This is mock data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
headers = list(df.iloc[:, 0])
indicies = list(range(len(headers)))
renamed = dict(zip(indicies, headers))
sub_df = df[['Afghanistan']]
sub_df.rename(columns=renamed, inplace=True)
result = sub_df.transpose()
print(result)
```