# Transposing a dataframe maintaining the first column as heading

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I have a big dataframe, but small example would be like this:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = c(letters[1:10]), M1 = c(11:20), M2 = c(31:40), M3 = c(41:50))
```

I want to transpose the dataframe and maintain the column 1 (A) as column heading ( letter[1:10]) as variable names. The following are scratch trials of unsuccessful codes.

```
tmydf = data.frame(t(mydf))
names(tmydf) <- tmydf[1,]
```

Thanks;

Comment: You don't need to call `c` for sequences created with a colon.  So `11:20` is the same as `c(11:20)`, and `letters[1:10]` is the same as `c(letters[1:10])`.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Here is one way

```
tmydf = setNames(data.frame(t(mydf[,-1])), mydf[,1])
```

Comment: There several similar threads around, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645524/what-is-the-best-way-to-transpose-a-data-frame-in-r-and-to-set-one-of-the-column  or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778908/r-transposing-a-data-frame . I like your answer best so far, +1. It's simple, reliable and keeps numeric as it is.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this perhaps:

```
tmp <- as.data.frame(t(mydf[,-1]))
> colnames(tmp) <- mydf$A
> tmp
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
M1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
M2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
M3 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Answer (score 6):

One more way using `janitor::row_to_names()` with `dplyr`/`magrittr` pipes

```r
mydf <- data.frame(A = c(letters[1:10]), M1 = c(11:20), M2 = c(31:40), M3 = c(41:50))


library(janitor, warn.conflicts = F)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
mydf %>% t %>% as.data.frame() %>% row_to_names(1)

#>     a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
#> M1 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#> M2 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
#> M3 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` functions from the `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyr)
mydf%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(-A),names_to="Original_Vars")%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(A))
```

The `pivot_longer` makes a column called "Original_Vars", and a new column called `value`.  If you stopped here, you'd have a row for each combination of your `A` variable, your "Original_Vars" (being M1, M2, and M3 here), and the value associated with that pairing.

The `pivot_wider` then takes all your values from the "A" column and turns them into columns, using the values from the `value` column we created with `pivot_longer` to  fill in.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (a tidyverse solution)!  SO needs a way to add tags to specific answers.  In this case, I'd choose: `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 1):

Data.table variante from Ramnath with indicating in string the variable name wanted.

```
mydf <- data.table(A = c(letters[1:10]), M1 = c(11:20), M2 = c(31:40), M3 = c(41:50))
tmydf <- setNames(data.table(t(mydf[,-"A"])), mydf[["A"]])
```