# What is the best way to turn a data set with first column headers and the data being in rows in R? How do I convert them to columns?

Tags: r

What is the best way to turn a data set with the first column being the headers and the data being in rows versus columns? How do I convert them to columns? I have transposed the data and then converted the first row to column headers but the class of my data changed.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: True...was in a hurry and didn't have time to include the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this answer:

```
tmydf = setNames(data.frame(t(mydf[,-1])), mydf[,1])
```

The source is from a thread with the exact same issue you're having here.

[Transposing a dataframe maintaining the first column as heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970179/transposing-a-dataframe-maintaining-the-first-column-as-heading)