# Transpose dataframe in R and maintain first column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, transpose

I need to transpose a dataframe in R, making the first column the headers of the transposed df, and the current columns headers the values in column 1 of the df. Like this -

```
df = 

 | |S1|S2|S3|
1|A|1 |2 | 3|
2|B|1 |2 | 3|

df_transposed = 

 |  |A |B |
1|S1|1 |1 |
2|S2|2 |2 |
3|S3|3 |3 |
```

I'm able to get part of the way there with the following code from this example - [Transposing a dataframe maintaining the first column as heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970179/transposing-a-dataframe-maintaining-the-first-column-as-heading)

```
# Sample data frame
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(10, 20, 30),
  Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
  Age = c(25, 30, 22)
)

# Transpose the data frame
df_transposed <-setNames(data.frame(t(df[,-1])), df[,1])
```

But every time it takes the column header values, in this case `'ID','Name','Age'`, and sets them as the index (or row.name in the r parlance). I've tried various solutions but nothing so far has worked. They're primarily geared towards the opposite - taking the first column and making it the index/row.names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this.

```
> setNames(data.frame(names(df)[-1], t(unname(df[, -1]))), c('Row.names', df[, 1]))
  Row.names    10  20      30
1      Name Alice Bob Charlie
2       Age    25  30      22
```

Please note, however, that column names beginning with a number are not considered syntactically valid, see `?make.names` on this.

To get automatically valid names we can exploit the `data.frame` which internally does `make.names`.

```
> data.frame(`colnames<-`(cbind(names(df)[-1], t(unname(df[, -1]))), c('Row.names', df[, 1])))
  Row.names   X10 X20     X30
1      Name Alice Bob Charlie
2       Age    25  30      22
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(10, 20, 30), Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"
), Age = c(25, 30, 22)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: That's almost there but `Name` and `Age` should be in column 1, instead of just removing them.

Comment: @JohnConor See update.

Comment: This is great, thanks!